# Listfragment button display in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

I am working on Android application in which I am using list fragment. I have added one button in the top of the layout. My problem is that it is repeating in every list option. I just want it to be displayed only one time in the top of INDIA option list.

My code with snap shots are given below:

```
public class CountryList extends ListFragment {


    Button btn1;
    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] countries = new String[] {
            "India",
            "Pakistan",
            "Sri Lanka",
            "China",
            "Bangladesh",
            "Nepal",
            "Afghanistan",
            "North Korea",
            "South Korea",
            "Japan"
    };    

    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable/
    int[] flags = new int[]{
            R.drawable.india,
            R.drawable.pakistan,
            R.drawable.srilanka,
            R.drawable.china,
            R.drawable.bangladesh,
            R.drawable.nepal,
            R.drawable.afghanistan,
            R.drawable.nkorea,
            R.drawable.skorea,
            R.drawable.japan    
    };

    // Array of strings to store currencies
    String[] currency = new String[]{
        "Indian Rupee",
        "Pakistani Rupee",
        "Sri Lankan Rupee",
        "Renminbi",
        "Bangladeshi Taka",
        "Nepalese Rupee",
        "Afghani",
        "North Korean Won",
        "South Korean Won",
        "Japanese Yen"
    };


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {  


        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();        

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            if(countries[i]=="India"){

            }
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);
            hm.put("cur","Currency : " + currency[i]);
            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );            
            aList.add(hm);        
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};        

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);       

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);     
    }

}
```

My XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"    
     >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/flag"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:contentDescription="HELLO WORLD"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >    

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15dp" />          

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/cur"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: you have to create a custom adapter for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have already made a custom layout for your list.

You'r using `SimpleAdapter`. But for your requirement you need to make a custom adapter to which you can implements as a `SimpleAdapter` or `BaseAdapter`. In that class you would be find a `getView()` method in which you can inflate your custom view and check the below condition.

```
  if(countries[position].eqauls("India")) {
      yourButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }else{
      yourButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
```

Comment: can you please provide me a code snippet for custom adapter here according to me condition. I am new to development thats why i don't have much experience in custom adapters.

Comment: Refer these links http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/ , http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/

Comment: it works, i used this link and make a custom Adapter and it works. I just want to know one more think i want to make click listener for my button to open a activity i am trying to do it by startActivity but on this point it is giving an error that: startActivity is not in the scope of BaseAdapter.. Can you please explain this thing to me, i want to make any event if i press this button.

Comment: Yes if you want to start activity from adapter class then you should use its context object like `context.startActivity(context , YourActivity.class);`

Comment: mViewHolder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        context.startActivity(context.getApplicationContext() , AlertMyNetwork.class);
       }
      });
I am trying to use it there but still it give me this error:                               The method startActivity(Intent, Bundle) in the type Context is not applicable for the arguments (Context, Class<AlertMyNetwork>)

Comment: There are two methods for startactivity. So you just need to use StartActivity(Intent) only and yes don't need to use context.getApplicationContext() instead of it just use context there.

Comment: By using this code Intent i = new Intent(context, AlertMyNetwork.class);
startActivity(i);   It is still giving me the same error. Please help me out here.

Comment: This `Intent i = new Intent(context, AlertMyNetwork.class); startActivity(i);` will be `Intent i = new Intent(context, AlertMyNetwork.class);` `context.startActivity(i);` Also must sure that `AlertMyNetwork` extends with Activity.

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding button in row_layout.. create new Xml with that button only..as add this layout as headerView for the listView.
this will add button on the top of list view.
let me know if issue arises,any!
cheers!

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {  


        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();        

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            if(countries[i]=="India"){

            }
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);
            hm.put("cur","Currency : " + currency[i]);
            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );            
            aList.add(hm);        
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};        

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);       
View headerView;
 headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null,false);
 getListView().addHeaderView(mHeaderView);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);     
    }
```